# php regex city state zip

Tags: php, regex

this is from an array i have

```
 [citystatezip] => New York, NY 50805-2578
```

i'm trying to have it in the format below

```
[city] => New York
[state] => NY
[zip] => 50805-2578
```

i was using regex in php..but got nowhere.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/([^,]+),\s*(\w{2})\s*(\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)/
```

Translated into code:

```
$str = "New York, NY 50805-2578";
preg_match("/([^,]+),\s*(\w{2})\s*(\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)/", $str, $matches);

list($arr['addr'], $arr['city'], $arr['state'], $arr['zip']) = $matches;
print_r($arr);
```

Gives:

```
Array
(
    [zip] => 50805-2578
    [state] => NY
    [city] => New York
    [addr] => New York, NY 50805-2578
)
```

With this regex:

- There is some input validation (eg: requires input to be in the form of: XXXXXXX, YY NNNNN-NNNN)
- Spaces are optional
- The last 4 digits of the zip are optional

Answer (score 0):

`(.+?), (\w+) ([-\d]+)`

Then get the info from the capturing groups.

Comment: you need to use the `ungreedy` / `?` in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do.

```
/(?P<city>[^,]+),\s*(?P<state>\w{2})\s*(?P<zip>\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)/
```

Saves you doing:

```
$arr['city'] = $matches[1];
$arr['state'] = $matches[2];
$arr['zip'] = $matches[3];
```

so when you:

```
print_r($matches);
```

you will get

```
Array
(
    [city] => New York
    [state] => NY
    [zip] => 50805-2578
)
```

Main expression used from `NullUserException` and all credit goes to him.  I just shortened the process.